# Bulb confusion - 1995 Camaro front turn signal

Tags: lights, camaro

I need to replace a front turn signal/DRL bulb in my 1995 Camaro (Canadian version). The owner's manual quotes the bulb part number as 2397, but when I look up the replacement on the Canadian NAPA site, it shows the correct bulb is a 3057. What's going on, and which is the correct one for my car? Is the manual in error or is the NAPA site? Is one of them for a US model instead of Canadian (using front turn signals as DRLs)?

Answer (score 3):

You probably already know this, but the difference is the connector. The bulb itself is basically the same. Your best bet is to pull your current bulb and see how the connector is. This will give you exactly what you need. The 3057 bulb is the new school version and has a flat connector. The 2397 is the old school version with the round brass base. I believe the one you probably need is the 3057, but I don't remember for sure (been a while since I have had my 94 Z28).